# Check/uncheck all child checkboxes jquery bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

With reference to this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7uR2B/), I've same functionality like this fiddle that is check/uncheck all child checkboxes and it is working fine as now it is.

But when i used this into my form and my form created under bootstrapvthen it other **DIV** and **SPAN** added to checkboxes and this fiddle script doesn't work more for bootstrap checkboxes.` Please help me regarding this to check/uncheck all child boxes.

```js
$('li :checkbox').on('click', function () {
    var $chk = $(this),
        $li = $chk.closest('li'),
        $ul, $parent;
    if ($li.has('ul')) {
        $li.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    }
    do {
        $ul = $li.parent();
        $parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox');
        if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
            $parent.prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
        } else {
            $parent.prop('checked', false)
        }
        $chk = $parent;
        $li = $chk.closest('li');
    } while ($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
});$('li :checkbox').on('click', function () {
    var $chk = $(this),
        $li = $chk.closest('li'),
        $ul, $parent;
    if ($li.has('ul')) {
        $li.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    }
    do {
        $ul = $li.parent();
        $parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox');
        if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
            $parent.prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
        } else {
            $parent.prop('checked', false)
        }
        $chk = $parent;
        $li = $chk.closest('li');
    } while ($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="checker"> <span><input type="checkbox"></span>

        </div>Administration
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="checker"> <span class="checked"><input type="checkbox"></span>

                </div>President
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                        </div>Manager 1
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                                </div>Assistant Manager 1</li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                                </div>Assistant Manager 2</li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                                </div>Assistant Manager 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                        </div>Manager 2</li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                        </div>Manager 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                </div>Vice President
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                        </div>Manager 4</li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                        </div>Manager 5</li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox"></span>
                        </div>Manager 6</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Screenshot of my form [a link]http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f549oknaf

Answer (score 2):

your Bootstrap version wasn't working, because the `checkbox` items are located in different place relative to the `ul` element (`$ul = $li.parent();`) that is used for searching the item. Your Bootstrap version:

```
  <div class="checker"> 
      <span class="checked">
          <input type="checkbox">
       </span>
  </div>President
  <ul>...
```

The original Fiddle version:

```
   <input type="checkbox" />President
   <ul>
```

I changed your Fiddled code slightly to take into consideration your changed element location in your Bootstrap version:

```
 do {
    $ul = $li.parent();
    //$parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox'); old code
    $parent = $ul.siblings('.checker');
    if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
        $parent.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
    } else {
        $parent.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false)
    }
    $chk = $parent;
    $li = $chk.closest('li');
} while ($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
```

The working sample can be found at [Bootply Fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/EPlC52DBMm).

Btw, your original Fiddle sample code was cool, it used a recursive loop in cool way to obtain parent elements :-)